# ORDS RESTful Service + Angular with Authentication

Tags: angular, oracle, oauth-2.0, oracle-apex, restful-authentication

So I'm not having much luck finding much info on how to do this so here we go. I am using Oracle Apex + Angular where I want my front end built in angular and then Oracle Apex as a middle man of the backend and front end using the RESTful API (hopefully I got that right, I am still learning how all this works).

So far I have successfully set up the RESTful service and am making calls to it from my angular front end and displaying data. I even got the Basic authentication to work. However, obviously that isn't very secure to have the username and password hard coded in there so I am trying to understand how to allow for the user to login/logout and get the Bearer token (expired after an hour) to then pass in when making GET requests instead.

From my little understanding, it seems like I would make a login page, use the entered information to make a call to the correct URL which then returns the token (or not based on if the login info is correct) to be used to make requests. However, I am worried about security with that and have no idea if that would be a secure method? I would like to do this correctly and as secure as possible for the knowledge and practice even though all the data in the DB is just test dummy data.

If that is a secure and correct way of doing it please let me know because I have no idea. If it isn't, if you could let me know why and the general idea of the correct way of doing this that would be awesome!

Here is the tutorial I found that gave me useful info: https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/ords-oauth-20-authentication-with-oracle-apex-v2

Answer (score 0):

[This page goes into some detail about the various authentication options available in ORDS.](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-authentication)

OAuth is generally used as third-party authentication (machine-to-machine), so I don't think it's a great fit for your use case. But neither are most of the first-party authentication scenarios.

I have a suggestion, it's a bit detailed so I'll just give a rough outline.

1. Create an Apex Application and use it to manage your users/passwords/authorization
2. Make your users log in to the Apex application through your Angular application - this will be the tricky part. The easiest way would be to use the Apex Application login page, and have it redirect to your Angular application after login. Alternately, you could create a dynamic process which could take user/password from Angular as an API call, run the `APEX_AUTHENTICATION.LOGIN` procedure, and return the session ID and cookie - ie, use the Apex app as an authentication backend without the user ever seeing an Apex page... it's possible, but I haven't seen anyone do it.
3. Once your Angular app has the Apex session_id and cookie, you can use First Party authentication for ORDS - just pass the cookie and `Apex-Session` HTTP header along with your calls to the RESTful API ([some documentation here](https://www.oracle.com/application-development/technologies/rest-data-services/listener-dev-guide.html)).

Apologies for the vague answer, but your use case is a bit unusual and I'm not really sure what a good answer would be.

Comment: After looking into it a bit more, Oracle has an Identity Cloud service that sounds like it would make what you were talking about, but not as complicated. At least it SOUNDS that it would be what I would want and allow for security while not having to pass users and passwords around. https://www.ateam-oracle.com/identity-cloud-service-mobile-clients-and-pkce-support and https://medium.com/scrum-and-coke/securing-angular-11-app-with-identityserver4-and-code-flow-pkce-5eddc68666b2 links have been very helpful.